# 2 column flex layout fills 100% of window but not window overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fluid-layout

I'm having an issue with a two column layout (sidebar + primary content). The goal is to have this fill 100% vertical space.

Currently it fills to the window, but if the content is below the window requiring you to scroll, the height of the flex container is only as large as the window.

**See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ab615v5/). Note how the sidebar fills the window in the bottom right, but when you scroll it does not expand to accommodate the window overflow**

HTML:

```
<div id="page_container">
    <div id="page_sidebar"></div>
    <div id="page_primary">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
    #page_container{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        flex: 1;
    }
    #page_sidebar{
        flex: 0 0 220px;
        background-color: #2E3254;
    }
    #page_primary{
        flex: 1;
        background-color: #F8F9FA;
    }
```

Comment: Please see my answer, you can get problem if you just remove `height:100%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` from your `#page_container`.

Comment: Wow simple fix! Thanks!

Comment: Note this solution actually causes the flex container to NOT fill the window unless the content overflows. I've found using 'min-height:100%;' accomplishes what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Height From #page_container

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
#page_container{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 flex: 1;
}
#page_sidebar{
 flex: 0 0 220px;
 background-color: #2E3254;
}
#page_primary{
 flex: 1;
 background-color: #F8F9FA;
}
```

```html
    <div id="page_container">
     <div id="page_sidebar">This is sidebar</div>
     <div id="page_primary">
      This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content
      
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the height of `#page_container` to 100% even if the content is not enough to fill the height. so you can use `min-height:100%` instead.

**Note:** removing `height:100%` will create trouble because your div no longer expand to 100% if there is no enough content. Hence you can safely use my method.

```css
html, body{
 height: 100%;
}
#page_container{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 min-height:100%;
 flex: 1;
}
#page_sidebar{
 flex: 0 0 220px;
 background-color: #2E3254;
}
#page_primary{
 flex: 1;
 background-color: #F8F9FA;
}
```

```html
    <div id="page_container">
     <div id="page_sidebar">This is sidebar</div>
     <div id="page_primary">
      This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content This is primary content
      
     </div>
    </div>
```